# RuntimeException Uncompilable source code - package does not exist in maven shade uber jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, gerrit, maven-shade-plugin

I'm writing a plugin for Gerrit, and one of the requirements according to the [Gerrit documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/dev-plugins.html#classpath) is that the plugin must have all its dependencies packed in a jar. They recommended using the [Maven Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) which is what I went with.

In my pom.xml I added my dependency on com.mypackage and the shade plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <finalName>uber-${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So I ran `mvn clean package` and it generated the uber-myplugin.jar. If I inspect the output of `jar xf uber-mypugin.jar`, my dependency .class files are there. Yet, when I try to use my plugin, I get

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
......
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.testplugin.CommitValidator$$FastClassByGuice$$a5e3cd18.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:61)
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - package com.mypackage does not exist
    at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.testplugin.CommitValidator.<clinit>(CommitValidator.java:32)
```

I maintain mvn on the command line, so this shouldn't have anything to do with an IDE.